# Dynamic query creation MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm working on a project using `mysqli` library, and I have reached the point where I need to create a `SELECT` query inside a method, depending on the parameters that were sent.

The behavior I'm looking for is similar to Android's `SQLite` where you pass the columns as a parameter and the values as the next paramenter.

I know I could create the query string if the parameter sent where the columns and the values, by iterating over them and then manually concatenating strings to a final query string, but I wonder if there is any core library that let you do this or any other way

Comment: Just use prepared statements and parameterized queries: http://us3.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [PDO prepared statements](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)

```
     //$param = array(":querycon1" => "querycon", ":querycon2" => "querycon2");
     // $condition = "abc=:querycon1 AND xyz=:querycon2";

     protected function setQuery($column,$condition,$param){
    
       $this->query = "SELECT $column FROM tablename WHERE $condition";

       $this->param = $param // 
    $this->getQuery($this->query, $this->param); // to a method that processes the query
}
```